# Rendering dynamic pages back into HTML with Scrapy and Splash

Tags: python, scrapy, scrapy-splash

In the following code I'm trying to render a JavaScript page into html using Scrapy_Splash but get getting the following error when I run my spider (TCP connection timed out 10060):

```
    2021-12-26 18:57:19 [scrapy.core.scraper] ERROR: Error downloading <GET https://www.tesla.com/en_ca/models/design#overview via h
ttp://172.17.0.1:8050/render.html>
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Users\Compuester\anaconda3\envs\scrapy\lib\site-packages\scrapy\core\downloader\middleware.py", line 44, in process_r
equest
    return (yield download_func(request=request, spider=spider))
twisted.internet.error.TCPTimedOutError: TCP connection timed out: 10060: A connection attempt failed because the connected part
y did not properly respond after a period of time, or established connection failed because connected host has failed to respond
..
```

The spider crawls (status code 200) but Splash doesn't render the page to the local host address back into HTML after JavaScript is rendered.

The code for the spider:

```
import scrapy
from scrapy_splash import SplashRequest

class TeslaSpider(scrapy.Spider):
    name = 'tesla'
    allowed_domains = ['tesla.com']
    start_urls = ['https://www.tesla.com/en_ca/models/design#overview',]


    def parse(self, response):
        for url in self.start_urls:
            yield SplashRequest(
                url,
                endpoint='render.html',
                args={
                    'wait': 2,
                    'html': 1,
                    'timeout': 10,
                })
            print(response.xpath("//title/text()"))
```

The settings.py file:

```
    # Scrapy settings for project project
#
# For simplicity, this file contains only settings considered important or
# commonly used. You can find more settings consulting the documentation:
#
#     https://docs.scrapy.org/en/latest/topics/settings.html
#     https://docs.scrapy.org/en/latest/topics/downloader-middleware.html
#     https://docs.scrapy.org/en/latest/topics/spider-middleware.html

BOT_NAME = 'project'

SPIDER_MODULES = ['project.spiders']
NEWSPIDER_MODULE = 'project.spiders'
SPLASH_URL = 'http://172.17.0.1:8050/'

# Crawl responsibly by identifying yourself (and your website) on the user-agent
#USER_AGENT = 'project (+http://www.yourdomain.com)'

# Obey robots.txt rules
ROBOTSTXT_OBEY = True

DOWNLOADER_MIDDLEWARES = {
    'scrapy_splash.SplashCookiesMiddleware': 723,
    'scrapy_splash.SplashMiddleware': 725,
    'scrapy.downloadermiddlewares.httpcompression.HttpCompressionMiddleware': 810,
}

SPIDER_MIDDLEWARES = {
    'scrapy_splash.SplashDeduplicateArgsMiddleware': 100,
}

DUPEFILTER_CLASS = 'scrapy_splash.SplashAwareDupeFilter'
HTTPCACHE_STORAGE = 'scrapy_splash.SplashAwareFSCacheStorage'
```

*I dont have a user agent listed there because Splash creates one for us

Using Scrapy with SplashRequests has been a **difficult** learning process.
I couldn't find clear documentation about how to integrate commands from [Scrapy_Splash/Splash Requests](https://github.com/scrapy-plugins/scrapy-splash) into python, only documentation from [Splash](https://splash.readthedocs.io/en/stable/) which gives details on Lua scripts and R language with a few examples-- which is my next plan if I dead end here.

A particularly stumping hurdle I went over was learning that using SplashRequests from **scrapy_splash** puts the "Yield" statements in the parse function whereas Splash *meta* classes from **import Splash** seen requiring a yield statement in a preceding function like

```
 def start_requests(self)
```

I look forward to hearing ideas and thoughts regarding this issue. Thanks

Answer (score 0):

I was able to fix the problem by specifying a USER_AGENT in the settings.py file. I think my mistake was thinking that Scrapy wouldn't need a User_agent because Splash was providing one. It appears they both need User_Agents to interact with the site, *or at least to render the website in splash browser* project settings needs to have a user agent.

Looking at the logs when Scrapy connects to the website it first provides the website with information about itself using the settings.py file. This happens before the spider is ran and therefore before the SplashRequest function performed meaning that the website is looking for a User_Agent to give the thumbs up to before  we even load the spider.

```
 (scrapy) C:\Users\Compuester\PycharmProjects\scrapy\project>scrapy crawl tesla
2021-12-27 12:31:16 [scrapy.utils.log] INFO: Scrapy 2.5.1 started (bot: project)
2021-12-27 12:31:16 [scrapy.utils.log] INFO: Versions: lxml 4.7.1.0, libxml2 2.9.12, cssselect 1.1.0, parsel 1.6.0, w3lib 1.22.0
, Twisted 21.7.0, Python 3.8.12 (default, Oct 12 2021, 03:01:40) [MSC v.1916 64 bit (AMD64)], pyOpenSSL 21.0.0 (OpenSSL 1.1.1m
14 Dec 2021), cryptography 36.0.1, Platform Windows-10-10.0.19043-SP0
2021-12-27 12:31:16 [scrapy.utils.log] DEBUG: Using reactor: twisted.internet.selectreactor.SelectReactor
2021-12-27 12:31:16 [scrapy.crawler] INFO: Overridden settings:
{'BOT_NAME': 'project',
 'DUPEFILTER_CLASS': 'scrapy_splash.SplashAwareDupeFilter',
 'HTTPCACHE_STORAGE': 'scrapy_splash.SplashAwareFSCacheStorage',
 'NEWSPIDER_MODULE': 'project.spiders',
 'ROBOTSTXT_OBEY': True,
 'SPIDER_MODULES': ['project.spiders'],
 'USER_AGENT': 'Mozilla/5.0 (iPad; CPU OS 12_2 like Mac OS X) '
               'AppleWebKit/605.1.15 (KHTML, like Gecko) Mobile/15E148'}
```

Above we see the user agent loaded from the settings.py file

```
(Bunch of code stuff happens, middeware etc)
2021-12-27 12:31:16 [scrapy.core.engine] INFO: Spider opened
```

Then spider is opened

There is an issue with this explanation because I did get a 200 code for Scrapy to crawl the website and then got the error code for Splash, but providing a user agent in settings.py allows splash to load the website for some reason.